# How can I sort a javascript array while ignoring articles (A, an, the)?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following sort function to sort a list of books:

```
var compare = function(a, b) {
  var aTitle = a.title.toLowerCase(),
      bTitle = b.title.toLowerCase();

  if (aTitle > bTitle) return 1;
  if (aTitle < bTitle) return -1; 
  return 0;
};
var sortedBooks = books.sort(compare);
```

How can I adjust this such that I ignore articles at the beginning of each title?

Comment: What do you mean by *"articles at the beginning of each title"*? Do you mean that each titles has more than a single work such as `"A Moive"` and you want to make it into `"Moive"` for comparison?

Comment: The OP means a substring.  "A New Hope" should be alphabetized with the N's, and "The Force Awakens" should be alphabetized with the F's.  "The Phantom Menace" should just be deleted, but that's a different problem than the OP is looking to solve.

Comment: Your compare just needs to test to see if the strings start with an article, and remove it if it exists.

Comment: To be clear you are sorting only 2 inputs at a time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply have a function say `removeArticles()` which checks if there is more than a single word in the sentence, if so return the second word for comparison. For specific words only you would need to add conditions for the words, for example `(words[0] == 'a' || words[0] == 'the' || words[0] == 'an')` would cover `"A"`, `"An"`, and `"The"`:

```js
books = ["A Whale", "The Moive", "A Good Time", "The Alphabet 2" , "The Alphabet 1", "Alphabet Soup", "Foo"];

var compare = function(a, b) {
  var aTitle = a.toLowerCase(),
      bTitle = b.toLowerCase();
      
  aTitle = removeArticles(aTitle);
  bTitle = removeArticles(bTitle);
  
  if (aTitle > bTitle) return 1;
  if (aTitle < bTitle) return -1; 
  return 0;
};

function removeArticles(str) {
  words = str.split(" ");
  if(words.length <= 1) return str;
  if( words[0] == 'a' || words[0] == 'the' || words[0] == 'an' )
    return words.splice(1).join(" ");
  return str;
}

var sortedBooks = books.sort(compare);

// [ "The Alphabet 1", "The Alphabet 2", "Alphabet Soup", "Foo", "A Good Time", "The Moive", "A Whale" ]
console.log(sortedBooks);
```

Comment: I see where you're heading, but this improperly alphabetizes a book with a title like "Alphabet Soup".

Comment: @YPCrumble Then in that case you would need to categorize each possible first word. For example `if(words[0] == 'a' || words[0] == 'the' || ... )`, I'll change it in an edit. *Updated*.

Comment: What about the rest of the words? Now you're sorting by the first one only

Comment: Change `return words.splice(1).join("");` to `return words.splice(1).join(" ");` so that "A Good Time" properly comes before "Goodness Gracious" and I think this is right :). Thank you!

Comment: > `var sortedBooks = books.sort(compare);`


Since `sort` actually modifies the list in place, the assignment to a new variable here is somewhat misleading. `sortedBooks = books.slice().sort()` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a *RegExp* to move them in your comparator. Also note that `.sort` has side-effects

```
function titleComparator(a, b) {
    var articles = ['a', 'an', 'the'],
        re = new RegExp('^(?:(' + articles.join('|') + ') )(.*)$'), // e.g. /^(?:(foo|bar) )(.*)$/
        replacor = function ($0, $1, $2) {
            return $2 + ', ' + $1;
        };
    a = a.toLowerCase().replace(re, replacor);
    b = b.toLowerCase().replace(re, replacor);
    return a === b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1;
}
```

And putting this into practice

```
var books = [
    'A Wonderful Life', 'The Beginning', 'An Everlasting Tale', 'I go in the middle'
];

var sortedBooks = books.slice().sort(titleComparator); // note slice
// ["The Beginning", "An Everlasting Tale", "I go in the middle", "A Wonderful Life"]
```