# Using javascript sort(); on an array of strings, but ignoring "The"

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of book titles alphabetically, while ignoring the word "the" if it is the first word in the title. I need to do it with javascript, no libraries.

```
// Sample Array
var books = ['Moby Dick', 'Hamlet', 'The Odyssey', 'The Great Gatsby', 'The Brothers Karamazov', 'The Iliad', 'Crime and Punishment', 'Pride and Prejudice', 'The Catcher in the Rye', 'Heart of Darkness'];
```

So right now if I run:

```
console.log(books.sort());
```

It's going to return:

```
["Crime and Punishment", "Hamlet", "Heart of Darkness", "Moby Dick", "Pride and Prejudice", "The Brothers Karamazov", "The Catcher in the Rye", "The Great Gatsby", "The Iliad", "The Odyssey"]
```

However I would like to know how I can sort while ignoring the first three letters if the title starts with "The" so it would return:

```
["The Brothers Karamazov", "The Catcher in the Rye", "Crime and Punishment", "The Great Gatsby", "Hamlet", "Heart of Darkness", "The Iliad", "Moby Dick", "The Odyssey", "Pride and Prejudice"]
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34347008/1028949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort function in javascript accepts a comparison function with each item to be compared as arguments. Within this function you can find and replace "The" with an empty string.

```
books.sort(function(a, b) { 
   // Return 1 left hand side (a) is greater, -1 if not greater.
   return a.replace(/^The /, "") > b.replace(/^The /, "") ? 1 : -1 
});
```